# Compare Author to UserID in SharePoint XSLT

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

I've got a simple DataFormWebPart where I'm using XSLT to render out the contents of list.  I want to compare the @Author field each list item to the current user, however the following won't evaluate to true:

in the header of the XSL:

```
<xsl:param name="UserID" />
```

and within the template that evaluates the rows:

```
<xsl:value-of select="@Author" /> 
<xsl:if test="@AuthorID = $UserID">(you)</xsl:if>
```

I have values for both @Author and $UserID:

- @Author renders as a hyperlink to their user-profile
- $UserID renders as the same text, but without the hyperlink.

What expression can I use to get the non-hyperlink value of the user-profile?

Comment: Can you post examples of what the contents of `@Author` and `$UserID` look like?

Comment: @Author = <a href="...">Last Name, First</a>
$UserId = Last Name, First

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a quick win:

```
<xsl:value-of select="contains(@Author,concat('&gt;',$UserID,'&lt;'))" />
```

Comment: If the format really is how you describe, this is as close as it gets. +1

Answer (score 1):

Should refer

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/21202/custom-form-does-not-display-created-by-value

```
<tr> 
<td valign="top" class="ms-formlabel"><nobr>Created by</nobr></td> 
<td valign="top" class="ms-formbody"> 
    <SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo ControlMode="Display" runat="server"> 
    <CustomTemplate> 
        <SharePoint:FormField FieldName="Author" runat="server" ControlMode="Display" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" /><br/> 
        <SharePoint:FieldValue FieldName="Modified" runat="server" ControlMode="Display" DisableInputFieldLabel="true"/> 
    </CustomTemplate> 
    </SharePoint:CreatedModifiedInfo> 
</td>
```